# How to make these types of rounded rectangular headings?

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox, tikz-styles

I'm stuck on how to format the boxes in code like below:

[image]

The adding and indented icon and the green upper-right-hand-corner text "Update" are the issues confusing me how to format.

Comment: Well, as usual here, please add the compilable code to your question ...

Comment: Plus you just asked a very similar question before. Wouln't it be better if you proceeded in small steps: get the answer to your previous question, learn a few new tricks from it, and then, if you really do not know how to this one, ask another question?

Comment: You probably want to look at tcolorbox and TikZ.

Comment: @marmot you're right I'll wait to see the other answer first!

Answer (score 4):

Based on box style provided by marmot's in [How to make this rectangle with an image on the left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455872/how-to-make-this-rectangle-with-an-image-on-the-left), here you have a box with a litle icon on left margin and an optional `update` label on the right corner. As I don't know how these boxes should be aligned to the text, I've provided two options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{%
    update/.style={%
        overlay app={%
            \begin{tcbcliptitle}
                \node[fill=green, font=\sffamily\bfseries, text=white, anchor=north east] at (frame.north east) {UPDATED};
            \end{tcbcliptitle}
        }
    }
}
\newtcolorbox{imagebox}[3][]{
    enhanced,
%   show bounding box,
    coltitle=black,
    title filled=false,
    colback=gray!20,
    colbacktitle=gray!20,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    top=2mm,
    bottom=2mm,
    toptitle=2mm,
    left=12mm,
    right=1mm,
    drop fuzzy midday shadow,
    titlerule=-0.1pt,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    title={#2},
    overlay={ 
        \begin{scope}
        \clip[rounded corners=1mm] ([shift={(-1cm,-.3cm)}]frame.north west) rectangle coordinate (center) ++(2cm,-2cm);
        \node at (center) {\includegraphics[ width=2cm, height=2cm]{#3}};
        \end{scope}
    },
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{imagebox}{some title}{example-image-duck}
\lipsum[2] 
\end{imagebox}

\begin{imagebox}[enlarge left by=1cm, width=\linewidth-1cm, update]{some title}{example-image-duck}
\lipsum[2]
\end{imagebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]